# Feed RSS sin contenido

Tags: php, xml

Muy buenas,

Estoy creando una feed RSS de la sección de noticias de mi web. Obtengo la información de la base de datos pero no sé si porque estoy implementando mal PHP en el fichero .xml no me está cogiendo la información. Ni siquiera me funcionan los comandos `var_dump` por ejemplo.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?php header("Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=utf-8"); ?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>Noticias LaXtore</title>
<link>http://www.ejemplo.com</link>
<description>Todas las noticias relacionadas con el mundo de los   videojuegos</description>
<?php
require 'admin/config.php';
try {
    $conexion = new PDO($bd_config['dbname'], $bd_config['usuario'],    $bd_config['password'] );
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "ERROR: ".$e->getMessage();
    die();
}
$statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM art ORDER BY   fecha_publicacion DESC");
$statement->execute();
$posts = $statement->fetchAll();

var_dump($posts);

foreach ($posts as $post) {
echo "<item>";
    echo "<title>" . $post['titulo'] . "</title>";
    echo "<link>noticas.php?ID=" . $post['ID'] . "</link>";
    echo "<description>" . substr($post['articulo'],300) . "   </description>";
echo "</item>";

}

?>
</channel>
</rss>
```

---

Actualizo al estar usando otro código que sí me funciona pero me da problemas al obtener la descripción de la base de datos y publicar imágenes.

```
<?php
// Elimina caracteres extraños que me pueden molestar en las cadenas que meto en los item de los RSS
function clrAll($str) {
$str=str_replace("&","&",$str);
$str=str_replace("'","'",$str);
$str=str_replace(">",">",$str);
$str=str_replace("<","<",$str);
return $str;
}

//creo cabeceras desde PHP para decir que devuelvo un XML
header("Content-type: text/xml");

//comienzo a escribir el código del RSS
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';

//sentencia SQL para acceder a los últimos 20 artículos publicados
require '../admin/config.php';

try {
   $conexion = new PDO($bd_config['dbname'], $bd_config['usuario'],     $bd_config['password'] );
} catch (PDOException $e) {
   header ('Location: error.php');
   echo "ERROR: ".$e->getMessage();
   die();
}

$statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM art ORDER BY    fecha_publicacion DESC");
$statement->execute();
$posts = $statement->fetchAll();

//Cabeceras del RSS
echo '<rss version="2.0" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"   xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd">';
//Datos generales del Canal. Edítalos conforme a tus necesidades
echo "<channel>\n";
echo "<title>Noticas LaXtore</title>";
echo "<link>http://www.laXtore.com</link>";
echo "<description>Desde laXtore facilitamos a los lectores estar al tanto de todas las noticias publicadas en la web a través de una feed  RSS</description>";
echo "<language>es-es</language>";
echo "<copyright>LaXtore.com</copyright>\n";

//para cada registro encontrado en la base de datos
//tengo que crear la entrada RSS en un item
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    echo "<item>\n";
    echo "<title>" . $post['titulo'] . "</title>\n";
    echo "<description>hola</description>\n";
    echo "<image>";
        echo "<url>http://www.imagenesfrases.net/wp-  content/uploads/2016/05/imagenes-con-frases-chistosas-para-reir-para-wasap.jpg</url>";
        echo "<title>W3Schools.com</title>";
        echo "<link>https://www.w3schools.com</link>";
    echo "</image>";
    echo "<link>http://www.laXtore.com/noticias/noticias.php?ID=" .    $post["ID"] . "</link>\n";
    echo "<pubDate>". $post['fecha_publicacion'] ."</pubDate>\n";
    echo "</item>\n";
}

//cierro las etiquetas del XML
echo "</channel>";
echo "</rss>";

?>
```

Comment: ¿Qué extensión tiene el fichero? Debería ser .php

Comment: Lo tenía en .xml, lo he cambiado a .php pero me sigue saliendo la misma información, sigue estando vacío vaya, tan sólo me aparece el título del feed, pero no el contenido. @AlvaroMontoro

Comment: ¿Cuál es el valor que tienes en `$bd_config['dbname']` (si se puede compartir)? Esto parece un error al conectarte a la base de datos. He probado el código y funciona bien (aparte de un par de cosillas que necesitarían cambios para funcionar mejor).

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro en ese campo está guardado el dato XboxOne. Es el nombre de la base de datos. He actualizado el post porque estoy usando otro código que si me funciona pero hay cosas que me dan problemas.

Comment: Creo que ese es el problema. Cuando se crea la conexión PDO, el primer parámetro no es el nombre de la base de datos sino el tipo, el host y el nombre de la base de datos (el Data Source Name, o DSN), algo como esto: `mysql:host=localhost;dbname=XboxOne`. Entonces tu conexión fallaría, y dejaría de ejecutarse el PHP que genera el RSS

Comment: La conexión a la base de datos es correcta, saco datos como el título o la fecha de publicación. La descripción me da problemas porque no es texto plano, tiene etiquetas y las imágenes no se ven, las que están dentro de las etiquetas <imagen>. @AlvaroMontoro